# How can I access my google drive or external hard from windows bash?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, google-drive

I want to download on my google drive or an external hard but when I run `ls /mnt/` the bash does not show me the external hard. Also when I go to my g drive which is my google drive I can not  yee the My Drive folder and access folders and instead it throw out this error:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Function not implemented
```

many thanks in advance for helping to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

If your external drive is d:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/d
sudo mount -t drvfs d: /mnt/d
```

Mounting Mount Google Drive File System is not supported yet.
https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2999